# SSH Config not prioritizing earlier stanza

Tags: ssh

I have an ssh config file that goes something like this:

```
(a bunch of specific entries)

Host appserver.*.*.foo.in
ControlMaster no

Host *
ForwardAgent yes
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%r@%h-%p
ControlPersist 300
```

Unfortunately, if I try to connect via something like

```
ssh dev.guid-1234-1234-1234@appserver.dev.guid-1234-1234-1234.foo.in -p 2222
```

I get an error about the control path being too long. Which is confusing, since I'm deliberately disabling ControlMaster to avoid that issue in the more specific ssh stanza, earlier in my config file.

Why is this config setting being ignored?

Answer (score 0):

`ControlMaster` controls whether an `ssh` instance will be a control *master*, not whether it uses the control feature at all. The [ssh_config man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config&sec=5) says this in part:

> **ControlMaster**
>   ...When set to “yes”, ssh(1) will listen for connections on a control socket specified using the ControlPath argument. Additional sessions can connect to this socket using the same ControlPath with ControlMaster set to “no” (the default). These sessions will try to reuse the master instance's network connection rather than initiating new ones, but will fall back to connecting normally if the control socket does not exist, or is not listening.

In other words, "ControlMaster no" still permits `ssh` to make use of an existing control socket if one exists. So it will still interpret `ControlPath` and look for a control socket.

If you want to disable the control feature for an ssh instance, set `ControlPath` to "none" as described in the man page.